# Div after div does not work as intended

Tags: html, css

I have div that needs to show after div, but it is showing before

Here is how it looks like

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOB6x.png)

Here is the code

```
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;border-style:solid;border-color:#1d69b4;margin-top:25px; white-space:nowrap;">
<div style="float:left; width:70%;height:100%;margin-left: 80px;">
    <div style="width:50%;height:30%;float:left;margin-top:20px;">
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;" />
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="from" name="from" placeholder="From" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;height:30%;float:right;margin-top:20px;">
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birth" name="birth" placeholder="Date of birth" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;" />
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="To" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;" />
        </form>
     </div>
    <div>sdkfhsdfgdsjfgjdf</div>
  </div>
```

But it must be after div, not before.

Where is trouble?

Comment: Use "clear: both"  like <div style="clear: both;">sdkfhsdfgdsjfgjdf</div>

Comment: That's because you're using `float` and I were just about to recommend you add `clear:both;` just like **Anupan** has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a closing div and the second div has a float left. This takes it out of the normal document flow. Add `float:left` to the other div, and it looks good.

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;border-style:solid;border-color:#1d69b4;margin-top:25px; white-space:nowrap;">
  <div style="float:left; width:70%;height:100%;margin-left: 80px;">
    <div style="width:50%;height:30%;float:left;margin-top:20px;">
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;" />
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="from" name="from" placeholder="From" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;height:30%;float:right;margin-top:20px;">
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birth" name="birth" placeholder="Date of birth" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;" />
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="To" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;border-width: 1px;" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">sdkfhsdfgdsjfgjdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```